# Dismiss one modalView and one pushView successively

Tags: iphone, ios, dismiss

How could i dismiss both tableView4 and tableView3 in tableView4's tableViewController?

**rootView(tableView1, one tab of a tabView, embeded in an navigationController)-->pushView1(tableView2)-->pushView2(tableView3)-->ModalView1(tableView4, embeded in an navigationController);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   UINavigationController *myNavController = [myViewController navigationController];
   [myViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [myNavController popToViewController:[myNavController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

call dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: on your modal view and then call popViewControllerAnimated: on the view you want to.

Comment: popViewControllerAnimated: in the completion? Could you plz kindly show me the code? I will really appreciate it.

Comment: No dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: is the name of the method. Basically, pushView1 should be the delegate of pushView2 and pushView2 should be the delegate of ModalView1. So when you want to dismiss ModalView1, send a message to the delegate (PushView2) and PushView2 is the one which should call dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: ! Then do the same for pushView2 but instead pushView1 should call popViewControllerAnimated: . I hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
UINavigationController *myNavController = [myViewController navigationController];
[myNavController popToViewController:[myNavController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[myViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```